# How to stop an Entry from making links blue in Xamarin Forms IOS Renderer?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uikit, xamarin.forms

I have written a custom IOS renderer for the forms entry box, using UIKit to change the Color. The entry box has a blue background with white text, this is ok. The problem occurs when there is a URL in the entry box, it automatically goes blue, which makes it practically invisible.

Is it possible to style all links in an entry white instead of blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TintColor](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.TintColor/) property of the renderer's underlying UITextField

Comment: I can't seem to find the underlying UITextField, I'm looking in the property inspector in OnElementChanged and I can see TextInputView and InputView, both of which are null.

Comment: check the Control property for the underlying iOS control